# Apache Camel - parallel processing in split slows down

Tags: camera, apache-camel

I have a list of 500 different Strings inside. I use split on list to process (fetch some data for this String from outside the app) each String in parallel. The things is that at the beginning it's super quick, but when it comes to the end, the process takes much much more time. So the last 5 (the biggest fetched objects by those Strings) are processed for 5-10 times longer than the previous.
I wonder if Camel is releasing the resources from previous finished threads or still occupying them somehow and blocking the performance for those who are not yet processed...
Is there any tool to observer running threads in background?
May I also somehow get rid of not used threads? I hope GC is doing it, but... I am not sure.

Comment: You can use JMX and JConsole to observe all resources that Camel app consumes.

Comment: @bvn13 do you mean camel tracer? Or how to use it?

Comment: no, I mean http://michalwarecki.blogspot.com/2012/08/monitoring-and-managing-apache-camel.html